# What is a good home station for mining low temp diamonds?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I want to make some money by mining low temp diamonds but I want to know what a good home station would be for doing this.

It should preferably not be too far away from anything and not too hard to get to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting up a long-term base of operations for mining isn't really that good of an idea. Mining hotspots become depleted the more they get mined out, so your yields will decline over time. Additionally, the selling price of the material you're mining will go down as the station that is buying receives its demand. What I recommend instead is looking for a *medium* term base of operations, which will shift pretty regularly.

[/r/EliteMiners](https://reddit.com/r/EliteMiners) has a good tool to help find good hotspots with good prices [here](http://edtools.ddns.net/miner), which I used to get my Elite trade rank.

At the moment, the tool indicates that there is a good spot to mine Low Temperature Diamonds in Borann A2 ring B 123.06 LY from Sol, and a good spot to sell at Noon Orbital in Goibniugo 46.59 LY from Borann, however, this information will shift based on the depletion of the hotspots and the sale price at Noon Orbital.

Be advised though: player pirates will also use this information to plan interdictions. Fly safe.

Comment: I still havent picked a home station yet so should I pick one near there or just in the middle of things.?

Comment: @Addy Typically I like to dock where I plan to sell, so Noon Orbital would be where I would go.

Comment: so would i set that as my home station or just use it as a place to work from?

Comment: @Addy Having a "home station" doesn't really matter unless you have multiple ships. That being said, any system around Sol with a starport close to the entry star is a decent choice if you have a fleet to store. (for instance, my fleet is docked in Fuelum, and I leave it there to take my mining ship wherever the EliteMiners tool tells me)

Comment: Actually, the reason Borann is such a good place is that it has three overlapping Low Temperature Diamond hotspots (that will change in the next content update for a technical reason). I wouldn't hesitate to simply always mine for Borann until the hotspots are reshuffled.

Comment: However, where to sell the diamonds is certainly a question where the answer will change almost every day. Inara (https://inara.cz/galaxy-commodity/144/) is a good way to gauge where the highest sell prices are, but be aware of the QTY listed. This represents the amount of demand, and if the amount of diamonds you're carrying in your hold is an appreciable percentage of demand, the amount you sell each diamond for will decrease, sometimes dramatically if the demand is low.